# Dividing a continuous domain into small squares; how to perform storage and querying?

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, discretization, data-structures

I recently had a software engineering interview and was asked a series of questions that was a bit outside of knowledge realm, and I feel like there's some scientific computing principles here (I took some scicomp courses many years ago, and I got some scicomp vibes when these questions were asked). I am wondering if anyone know what kind of problem this is? I suspect it's some kind of classical problem under guise.

> You're given a large rectangle that has length = n and width = m. The rectangle is divided into many disjoint areas and the areas comes in all shapes (not necessarily convex) and sizes. Each disjoint area is assigned a distinct ID. Assume there are approximately 200 of such disjoint areas/IDs. In addition, suppose you some giant matrix `mat` where `mat[i][j]` corresponds to some coordinate `(x=i, y=j)` and `mat[i][j]` represents the ID at that coordinate. But `mat` is so large you can't store it in memory. (I was a bit confused here because he said you're given this matrix but it's not stored in memory, so I don't quite see how you're "given" the matrix)

The first question I was asked:

> How would you turn `mat` in to an easy to store and more efficient memory structure? The idea the interviewer wanted here is to keep dividing the large rectangle into very small squares repeatedly until the area consists of a single ID (at which point you stop cutting that area into even smaller squares). Then save this square. This sounds straightforward and just like meshing.

The second question I was asked is:

> How would you store these squares? What data structure would you use? I think he wanted some kind of sorted way but I have no clue what he was referring to.

Does anyone know what would be a good storage structure here? It seems like it's just a mesh of squares, and I know there's traditional methods of storing structured and unstructured meshes (I highly highly doubt that's what the interviewer wanted though because that's pretty off topic for software engineers).

Then the last question was

> You're given a (x,y) coordinate, and you want to quickly query which ID this coordinate belongs to. How would you do this? I said you can use some sort of binary search (at this point, I was just making stuff up...) and the interviewer wanted me to think about "compressing x and y simultaneously." I don't even known what this means.

Does anyone know how you would quickly query the list of squares from the previous question? I suppose the answer to this depends on how its stored.

This third question reminds me of solving the Euler equations at "tracer" coordinates that didn't correspond to the centroids of the mesh elements, but in that situation, I just found the nearest neighbor and outputted the solution there. Don't think that's what was wanted here as an answer for this question however.

Comment: This problem looks like it can be solved using some data structure like a quadtree. Not exactly sure, though.

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas Would you be able to expand on the quadtree idea? I'm not sure how it applies in this scenario.

Comment: You can read the region quadtree article on wikipedia (I linked in my answer). But TL;DR: the root is the whole matrix; you check if all entries are the same, the moment you find two entries with different IDs create 4 leaves, repeat the procedure for each leaf. If a leaf has no children, then store the region ID in that leaf. For leaves with children, put the region ID = NULL because they contain multiple regions.

Comment: If it doesn't fit into memory, it might still fit onto a harddrive. Algorithms can then only work on parts of the data structure at a time. These are called "out of core" algorithms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing some quick research, I am convinced that the interviewer was looking for an answer related to one of the data trees. Depending on the application, one might be better than the others, but all of them are suitable for this general description.

`mat[i][j]` might be available on a hard disk -which are capable of storing 16TBs of data nowadays- but may not be possible to read into the memory -the best consumer-level motherboard I could find supports only upto 256 GBs-. In this case, you would read the matrix in chunks and process incrementally.

I would probably answer with quadtrees ([region quadtrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree#Region_quadtree)), because that is a structure I am familiar with. But there are many like R-trees, Kd-trees, ... See wikipedia.

Querying to which leaf a point belongs (which would correspond to finding the ID it belongs to) costs $O(N)$ assuming the matrix `mat` is $2^N$-by-$2^N$. See [this image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d7/Quadtree_compression_of_an_image.gif/300px-Quadtree_compression_of_an_image.gif), where an image is compressed using quadtrees. To find the color of a pixel, you would query the tree and retrieve color information stored at the corresponding leaf.

Comment: I will look into quadtrees before I read your answer in more detail. Does binary search come into play here? That seemed to be along the right lines during the interview, but it seems quad trees aren't related to binary searching.

Comment: Honestly, the question you were asked is a little ambiguous. This is not surprising to me, as I went through some amount of technical interviews this year. In my experience, this is not intentional, in their context the question is clear because they have been working on a related project for a while. Same as the "obvious" trap grad students (even some experienced academics) commonly fall into, the terminology and techniques are obvious to them but not to other people (I know because I was a grad student too).

Comment: In this case, maybe you could do something with binary search. Though I don't know how that would work, because given `i` and `j` if you could access `mat[i][j]` easily, then you wouldn't have to search. And I don't know how you would do binary search on a bunch of differently sized rectangles. But that is not the point. There is a correct answer to this question (in their mind, it may even be unique) and they probably are looking for someone who can give that (or at least get to) that answer (with/out some help from the interviewer). I think the answer was quadtrees in this case.

Comment: Nevertheless, even though the binary search could be applicable here, it is your responsibility to convince them that it is a solution and a good one. That is a lesson I learned during my interviews, together with "If it is ambiguous to you, ask for clarification", "Don't be shy to ask 'can I refer to a source I know that contains the answer?'", "If you don't know, don't be afraid to say 'I do not know but I think...'" and "The interviewer is there to measure not only your capabilities but also your growth potential".

Comment: I guess if you were given the coordinates of the squares, then you could sort them by their $y$-coordinates on top, you can do a binary search to identify the squares which may contain `i,j` and then sort those matrices by their $x$-coordinates a left then do another binary search to find the square you want. Initial sort would cost $O(K\log K)$ where $K$ is the number of the squares, then you are going to binary search on that which is $O(\log K)$, the rest of the operations may be negligible since they are sort and search on a smaller number of squares. The total cost is $O(K\log K)$.

Comment: I'm going to look into all of this tomorrow morning. My brain is too fried right now to process this. Just letting you know so you don't think I ditched the discussion :)

Comment: Just a quick comment: as far as I remember, numerical recipes has an implementation of a KD-tree, including binary search and things like that.

Comment: @davidhigh, they do. I like Numerical Recipes similar to the way I like MATLAB. Both are convenient and they let you work at a higher level of abstraction. I similarly hate both, because neither of them are very accessible (financially) for people outside of Western/Central Europe and North America (this is their fault, some price discrimination wouldn't hurt), and there are not any comprehensive open-source/free tools to replace them (this is hardly their fault, it is more on me -or people like me- complaining rather than contributing when they have skills to do so).

Comment: Regarding your binary search idea. After you sort by y centroid coordinate, I'm not seeing how you can use binary search "to identify the squares which may contain i,j." Wouldn't you need to know the size of these squares too? I think having the centroid information alone isn't sufficient to determine which squares might contain the given coordinate.

Comment: Firstly, the binary search approach is not good; because the levels $N$ will always be less than or equal to the number of squares $K$, so the binary search is more expensive. Secondly, after sorting by the topmost y-coordinate of each square, you can do your comparison using all the coordinates of the square and so on. I was just trying to come up with a loose idea using binary search, as you asked. I didn't think it through all the way.

Comment: Just looked through the quadtree approach! It's pretty simple unless I'm missing something. It's funny because I actually had an algorithms problem last week on quadtrees, but I didn't know the terminology at that time. Are quadtrees used frequently in computational sciences? Under "Some common uses of quadtrees," it looks like it's used during mesh generation.

Comment: It is a simple idea, definitely. Efficiently implementing it is difficult, but that is the case with most numerical algorithms. It can be used in mesh generation, and mesh refinement, but can also be used in particle simulation: most commonly in astronomy and subatomic physics. It is a nice data structure which implicitly encodes spatial relationships; it has many uses.

Comment: Do you know if quadtrees are how countries are identified given latitude and longitude coordinates? Seems like a (2D) world map could be stored as a quad tree.

Comment: That approach would have a lot of diplomatic consequences, could cause wars (similar to Google Maps almost causing wars, see https://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2010/11/google-maps-nearly-starts-a-war/66451/ or many other incidents after 2010). So I hope noone is doing that. But my coauthors and I did something similar for a paper back in 2015, we took a geographic area and use quadtrees to store the relevant data and to search and retrieve nearby points to a given point efficiently. Definitely, it has uses in GIS.